# JAVA service provider SAML2 request - disable digital signature

Tags: java, .net, spring-boot, digital-signature, saml-2.0

I'm trying to integrate a Java SP (service provider) with an existing IDP (.net)
My problem is that my service provider is sending the request with < SignedInfo> which I don't need.

Is there a way to enable/disable this on demand?

(I'm using spring-security-saml2-core and providing the IDP provider using xml)

What I need is something like this:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest ID="_66a1c753-1636-4fbc-8f5d-313b19579558"
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="2018-11-07T22:48:54.286Z"
                Destination="http://localhost:44101/SAML/SSOService"
                ForceAuthn="false"
                IsPassive="false"
                ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:30941/SAML/AssertionConsumerService"
                xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:componentspace:My-Localhost</saml:Issuer>
```

but my java client is sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"                AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO"
                 Destination="http://localhost:44101/SAML/SSOService"
                 ForceAuthn="false"
                 ID="a4065059de35d17j11h270ai65i44hj"
                 IsPassive="false"
                 IssueInstant="2018-11-08T17:01:16.853Z"
                 ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                 Version="2.0"> <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">localhost-demo</saml2:Issuer> <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
  <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
  <ds:Reference URI="#a4065059de35d17j11h270ai65i44hj">
    <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <ds:DigestValue>RBuhWuT4+my+G95BEKpRam2l/qs=</ds:DigestValue>
  </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>NNy2s52kGCuQQADw7RdCAmAO4chm7BDjW0EJfdyvsgtdygdyrgyhdPNPv9LX2N+XT+syOqUm2VAOlMntBm/BpDkiAi3exIXR/lwph04ehKL6x5WladLCzEaRLOBE0LrFw+WdYOULZp+MRmMN8SsW8XOc5ItVdfhDHBbnUurthi3V7Uq/Q6lfzU9QlxywfMJirWHg==</ds:SignatureValue>   < ds:KeyInfo>
  <ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIC+zCCAeOgAwIBAgIJdfsdgfsdartesgtrygerytoa+K66EA4u7DpE oHJBlqH0AVWAd8q9488DpCo1x4ujTGw7AHE=</ds:X509Certificate>
  </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>  </ds:Signature>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [Configuration metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html)  to find out details to edit SP metadata. You can add and make attribute `requestSigned` as false in case authentication request need not be signed. By default the value will be true.